# Problems calling webservice - javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException and class do not have a property of the name

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl, cxf

I have a wsdl file, lot of xsd files, jxb binding file. I created a web service client using Apache CXF cxf-codegen-plugin. Java classes are created without any errors. But when I try to call any of the generated methods, I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class com.amadeus.xml.pnracc_11_1_1a.PNRReply do not have a property of the name {http://xml.amadeus.com/PNRACC_11_1_1A}PNR_Reply
```

I call the webservice method like this (don't worry about the nulls):

```
AmadeusWebServices aws = new AmadeusWebServices();
aws.getAmadeusWebServicesPort().fareMasterPricerCalendar(null, null);
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class com.amadeus.xml.pnracc_11_1_1a.PNRReply do not have a property of the name {http://xml.amadeus.com/PNRACC_11_1_1A}PNR_Reply
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ValueSetter$AsyncBeanValueSetter.<init>(ValueSetter.java:165)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ValueSetterFactory$AsyncBeanValueSetterFactory.get(ValueSetterFactory.java:67)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIMethodHandler.buildResponseBuilder(SEIMethodHandler.java:163)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.AsyncMethodHandler.<init>(AsyncMethodHandler.java:121)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.PollingMethodHandler.<init>(PollingMethodHandler.java:39)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.initMethodHandlers(SEIStub.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:73)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:590)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:330)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:312)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:294)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
at com.amadeus.xml.AmadeusWebServices.getAmadeusWebServicesPort(AmadeusWebServices.java:78)
at com.mycompany.test1.App.main(App.java:16)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: {http://xml.amadeus.com/PNRACC_11_1_1A}PNR_Reply is not a valid property on class com.amadeus.xml.pnracc_11_1_1a.PNRReply
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:966)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ValueSetter$AsyncBeanValueSetter.<init>(ValueSetter.java:162)
... 13 more
```

My environment:

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-5)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
NetBeans IDE 7.3.1
```

Am I missing something? I am jus trying to create very simple web service client.
I've put sample project with all the wsdl and xsd files I'm using on [GitHub](https://github.com/skmichi23/webservices)

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you hit a bug in Oracle's JAX-WS implementation.  If you add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

to the dependencies to use CXF's JAX-WS implementation, it seems to  work OK.   I also tried generating the code with the wsimport command and get the same error so the generated code seems OK.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, after adding that dependency I can successfuly call the webservice methods. However another exceptions arised after trying to deploy simple JAXRS application to glassfish, I created new question, you can watch it here if you're interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045664/how-to-deploy-apache-cxf-webservice-to-glassfish

Comment: @Daniel Kulp Does anyone know what exactly the bug is? and why hasn't it been fixed :(

Comment: For me it was the return type of a HashMap which was actually not supported by JBoss Wildfly. Adding this dependency solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue and find that it occurs because of encoding issues in generated java class, it is interesting that it throws same exception.
[image: Encoding Error Screenshot]
You can generate java class with wsimport -keep and check java classes for this issue.