# jaxws and apache cxf and glassfish 5 error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The lifecycle method [finalizeConfig] must not throw a checked exception

Tags: java, soap, glassfish, jetty, cxf

I saw  [this and other similar  questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045664/how-to-deploy-apache-cxf-webservice-to-glassfish)  before and their solution didn't solve my problem because Glassfish 5 had a lot of changes.

I'm running a soap web service and getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The lifecycle method [finalizeConfig] must not throw a checked exception. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.annotation.PostConstruct()] on annotated element [public void org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.spring.JettyHTTPServerEngineBeanDefinitionParser$SpringJettyHTTPServerEngine.finalizeConfig() throws java.security.GeneralSecurityException,java.io.IOException] of type [METHOD]
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:503)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:397)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:372)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:256)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:217)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:73)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:797)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:195)
...
```

I'm using Glassfish 5.1.0 and using Apache cxf 3.3.5 and my IDE is Eclipse EE Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)

I downloaded Apache CXF binary distribution and added in to eclipse CXF runtime.

This is my web service class:

```
package com.web.service;

import javax.jws.WebMethod; 
import javax.jws.WebService; 

@WebService(targetNamespace = "localhost:8080")
public class Service { 
    @WebMethod public String greet(String name) { 
        return "Hi," + name; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've formatted your code. Please check the general help pages for your next question. Please don't add comments to clarify; code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: Thank you very much. I read them, but need a little practice.

Answer (score 0):

The `org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.spring` package causes problems when deployed to Glassfish. You need to remove that from the CXF binary distribution.

Please try the following steps:

First remove the original binary distribution from your project in Eclipse.
Then you need to open the binary distribution with some archive tool (maybe the  operating system you are using contains something already) and navigate to the `lib` folder in the archive. Delete the file `cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-*.jar`.
Then add the changed binary distribution to your project like you did before with the original binary distribution.

Maybe this will already be sufficient. If not, there is another step you can try.

It is more or less the same solution that you linked already. However, I am not sure if Glassfish 5.1 will still accept the `sun-web.xml` file. It should be named `glassfish-web.xml` nowadays.

So create the file `glassfish-web.xml` with following content:
(if you already have that file, only add the `<class-loader delegate="true"/>` line to it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Put the file into the `WEB-INF` folder of your WAR file.

Comment: Thanks. I did what you said and it gets another error.  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The lifecycle method [finalizeConfig] must not throw a checked exception. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.annotation.PostConstruct()] on annotated element [public void org.apache.cxf.transport.http_undertow.spring.UndertowHTTPServerEngineBeanDefinitionParser$SpringUndertowHTTPServerEngine.finalizeConfig() throws java.security.GeneralSecurityException,java.io.IOException] of type [METHOD]
 at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:503)
...

Comment: Then please also remove the undertow transport from the binary distribution. Just as you did with the jetty transport.

Comment: There is 3 files that have undertow on them.
cxf-rt-transports-http-undertow-3.3.5.jar, undertow-core-2.0.28.Final.jar and undertow-servlet-2.0.28.Final.jar.
Do I need to remove all of them? are you sure that nothing goes wrong?
Cheers.

Comment: The one for the transport should be enough. What do you have to lose? ;)

Comment: after removing file: java.lang.RuntimeException: wsdl file classpath:/org/apache/cxf/ws/discovery/wsdl/wsdd-discovery-1.1-wsdl-os.wsdl does not exist for web service Discovery
 at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ModuleContentValidator.accept(ModuleContentValidator.java:181)
 at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ModuleContentLinker.accept(ModuleContentLinker.java:67)
 at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:617)
 at org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor.WebBundleDescriptorImpl.visit(WebBundleDescriptorImpl.java:2009)

Comment: Did you add the glassfish-web.xml? What is the structure of your WAR file? Does it contain the CXF distribution or do you deploy that separately?

Comment: Eclipse creates glassfish-web.xml automatically and I just added <class-loader delegate="true" />.
in package explorer, I have: TestService\  src,jre, glassfishSystemLibraries, ApacheSystemLibraries, build, webContent.
TestService is the name of my project.
Because I added Cxf in preferences as default runtime and selected it in the facets, eclipse automatically adds it to the project.
I can upload it on github or somewhere if neded.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes please upload to github.